# create active link to send a mail xml

Tags: html, xml, xslt, hyperlink

I would like to create an active mailto:-link in my xsl. however all the explanations do not work as they should, as often they have the mail adress in plain text. however I have multiple mail adresses which are made visible in cards.

i would like to do sth. like
<a href="mailto:*<xsl:value-of select="Mail"></xsl:value-of>*">Example mailto link
but that does not work as it should unfortunately.

```
<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Mail: 
 <a href="#" class="card-link">                          
   <!--<xsl:value-of select="Mail"></xsl:value-of>-->
 </a>
</h6>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside attribute values, you can simply use brace notation instead of `xsl:value-of`:

```xml
<a href="mailto:{Mail}" class="card-link">...</a>
```

Comment: These are called "Attribute Value Templates" in the XSLT 1.0 specification  https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates